# ArrayList to parse and return JSON data

Tags: java, arrays

iam student and i have this class for parse and return json data and i used a string array and i want to change the string array to ArrayList but i get stuck with it how can i use ArrayList to parse and return results

this is my attempts :

```
public static String[] getStringsFromJson(Context context, String JsonString)
            throws JSONException {

        final String RESULTS = "results";
        final String SUBJECT = "subject";

        ArrayList<ListItem> ItemsList;

        JSONObject Object = new JSONObject(JsonString);
        JSONArray ItemsList = Object.getJSONArray(RESULTS);

        for(int i = 0; i < ItemsList.length; i++)
        {

            JSONObject object = ItemsList.getJSONObject(i);
            Item ci = new Item();
            String subject = object.getString(SUBJECT);
            ci.toString(subject);
           ItemsList.add(ci);
        }
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: You need to show some more research effort - explain what you did so far to solve the issue, show the work.

Comment: i want to change the string array to ArrayList any tips to help me do that

Comment: for(String x:parsedMovieData) yourArrayList.add(x);

Comment: i have tried of course i will edit the code and add my attempts

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You forgot just to get a new instance of the array list here `ArrayList<MovieItem> moviesItemsList = new ArrayList<MovieItem>();`

Do it like this :

```
public static ArrayList<MovieItem> getSimpleMovieStringsFromJson(Context context, String moviesJsonString)
        throws JSONException {

    final String RESULTS = "results";
    final String POPULARITY = "popularity";
    final String POSTER_PATH = "poster_path";
    final String ORIGINAL_TITLE = "original_title";

    ArrayList<MovieItem> moviesItemsList = new ArrayList<MovieItem>();

    JSONObject moviesObject = new JSONObject(moviesJsonString);
    JSONArray moviesItemsList = moviesObject.getJSONArray(RESULTS);

    for(int i = 0; i < moviesItemsList.length; i++)
    {

        JSONObject object = moviesItemsList.getJSONObject(i);
        MovieItem ci = new MovieItem();
        String original_title = object.getString(ORIGINAL_TITLE);
        ci.toString(original_title);
        moviesItemsList.add(ci);
    }

    return moviesItemsList;
}
```

Comment: I just get red line under this code MovieItem ci = new MovieItem(); why

Comment: have you created the `MovieItem` Class ??

Comment: and what is the error when you hover the red line ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `parsedMovieData`, use this:

```
List<String> parsedMovieList = new ArrayList<>(moviesArray.length());
parsedMovieList.add(popularity + " - " + poster_path + " - " + original_title);
```